# Csr matrix: How to replace missing value with np.nan instead of 0?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, scipy.stats

It seems that `csr_matrix` fill missing value with `0` in default. So how to fill the missing value with `np.nan`?

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Expected:

```
array([[0, np.nan, 2],
       [np.nan, np.nan, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'missing values'?  The `scipy` sparse matrix format(s) stores non-zero values.  The rest are 0's.  Period, full stop!  I doubt if you'll find "missing" in any of the scipy.sparse documentation.

Comment: The scipy sparse class, especially the `csr` format, is designed for math, especially linear algebra and matrix multiplication.  A `nan` fill would behave in a very different way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

mask = csr_matrix(([1]*len(data), (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
mask[mask==0] = np.nan

csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray() * mask
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with csr_matrix, which by definition stores nonzero elements.

If you *really* need those nans, just manipulate the dense result.

```
a=csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
a[a == 0] = np.nan
```

Comment: Emm, It's not my expectation. My original data contains `0`, but I don't want to change it to `np.nan`. I only want to fill missing value with `np.nan`. BTW, I cannot run your code successfully as an error occurs like `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`.

Comment: Well, then csr_matrix cannot meet your expectations :-). W.r.t. the error, it's just what is says: your matrix contains integers, and there is no integer nan. If you want nans, specify `dtype=float`.

Comment: This will convert all 0 values to NaN, this is not a correct solution as the OP wants a result with NaN values and 0 values. The solution needs to retain both zeros and NaNs in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def todense_fill(coo: sp.coo_matrix, fill_value: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """Densify a sparse COO matrix. Same as coo_matrix.todense()
    except it fills missing entries with fill_value instead of 0.
    """
    dummy_value = np.nan if not np.isnan(fill_value) else np.inf
    dummy_check = np.isnan if np.isnan(dummy_value) else np.isinf
    coo = coo.copy().astype(float)
    coo.data[coo.data == 0] = dummy_value
    out = np.array(coo.todense()).squeeze()
    out[out == 0] = fill_value
    out[dummy_check(out)] = 0
    return out
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.